# Date format in Chinese

Tags: calendar

I would like to display dates in different scenarios as given below. Could someone please help with correct Chinese date format for each case. I tried to find but coudldn't find something useful,so I thought better to ask here.

Date

**format → dates are the same**

1 Jan

**format → dates are different**

1 Jan - 4 Feb

**format → same month**

1 - 4 Feb

Comment: Everything in Chinese is big endian, i.e the most significant stuff appears first.

Answer (score 1):

In traditional Chinese:

- "1 Jan" is written "一月一日" or "1月1日".
- "1 Jan - 4 Feb" is often written "一月一日～二月四日" or "1月1日～2月4日".
- "1 - 4 Feb" is often written "二月一日～四日" or "2月1日～4日".

(Sentences like "從一月一日到二月四日" is also used, like "from 1 Jan to 4 Feb" in English. One uses "從", "自" for "from", and uses "到", "至" for "to".)

Answer (score 0):

**1 Jan -** 元月一日; 一月一號

**1 Jan - 4 Feb -** 元月一日至二月四日; 一月一號到二月四號

**1 - 4 Feb -** 二月一號至(到)四號

Comment: BTW, the more common way to say 一月一號 in the lunar calendar  is 正月初一 (大年初一), 元月 is  used in the  lunar calendar more often (when I hear 元月, the first thing in my mind is  the first month of the lunar  calendar)

Comment: @TangHo "元旦" is 一月一號, the first day of the year (公元). Similarly, 元月 is the first month of the year. Agreed, that 正月 is the first month in the lunar calendar/year.

Comment: 元旦 is used in both 公曆 and 農曆; 元 means 'the beginning' e.g. 康熙元年, 令和元年

Comment: @TangHo Agreed.

Answer (score 0):

- 1 Jan  =  一月一号
- 1 Jan - 4 Feb = 一月一号到二月四号
- 1-4 Feb = 二月1号到4号。

Let's forget the traditional Chinese.

Answer (score 0):

1 Jan = 1月1日

1 Jan - 4 Feb = 1月1日-4月4日

1 - 4 Feb = 4月1日-4月4日

Just like above,we write like that widely in documents,reports,news,papers and daily life.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to put the answers in a table, please see the picture below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

A modern Chinese input program will give the hint. And you don't have to input the date detail.

[image]
[image]